# HTML alternatives to make website?

Tags: html, xml, xhtml, sgml, wml

I am using **HTML** to make a websites. I know an alternative languages to markup a website: **XHTML**, **WML**. Is there any more markup languages? Can I make a website only with **XML** or **SGML**?

Thank you for responses.

Answer (score 2):

There aren't many.

To have a browser make your website viewable, you must provide your website in some language your browser can understand. Just plaintext and HTML work universally, there is quite some SVG and PDF support these days, but the only language you can use that can do all the things most people want a website to be able to do, you will have to use HTML or XHTML in some way. Either through JS or by some templating system, but you'll have to use it to generate what's commonly accepted as being a webpage as far as I'm aware.

That being said, there are some languages like Haml, which can be 'compiled' to HTML so you could use that instead. There are also converters for other XML-based languages and such.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deliver XML from your server, you can convert it to HTML in the browser using either

(a) XSLT 1.0: nearly all browsers have built in support for XSLT 1.0, which can be invoked using the xml-stylesheet processing instruction embedded in the XML

(b) XSLT 3.0: supported using Saxon-JS, which can be invoked using a small Javascript call in a skeletal HTML page.

(c) CSS: if the XML is reasonably close in structure to what you want to present to the user, you can attach styling properties to the XML elements using CSS.

You can also of course maintain your content in XML and convert it to rendered HTML using XSLT either at publishing time, or when each page is requested using code on the server to do the conversion on demand.

Comment: Note that if you use (c) raw XML with CSS, you won't have interactivity (hyperlinks, inputs, scripts etc), only static content.

Answer (score 0):

Many scientific journals use XML (actually JATS XML) for publishing scientific articles. XML in this case is transforming to HTML either on server or on client side by javascript. As example you can look [here](https://lens.elifesciences.org/22431/index.html?_ga=1.120965697.832132021.1487796339), where taking place client-side transformation. But Google will not index such XML.